# Can I use left alt to type dead keys and use the alt-tab application switcher?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

I’m on Ubuntu 12.10 and I’ve seen that I can use

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

to control which key triggers the dead key behaviour on my keyboard (which normally resides on <kbd>AltGr</kbd>). I would like to use both <kbd>Alt</kbd> as well as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to type dead keys.

However, when I select *Both Alt Keys* in the **Key to function as AltGr** step, the <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> application switcher shortcut stops working, presumably because the key combo is swallowed by whatever controls text input. Is there any way to make both work, since there is no dead key on tab?

Comment: Is that for 'dead key' configuration, or is it to switch to different keyboard layouts?

Comment: @user4124 I don’t quite know what you’re getting at: The utility I mentioned lets me change keyboard layouts. Some layouts have dead keys and some of these are activated only with AltGr pressed. One screen in said utility lets me choose which key to use for “AltGr” (if not AltGr). I can choose to use “Both Alt Keys”, which is what I would like to use as it mimicks how the Mac’s dead keys work. Unfortunately, this makes alt-tab inoperable for app-switching even though there is no dead key on tab. I would like to use both the app-switcher as well the dead keys with left alt.

Comment: possibly http://blog.andrewbruce.net/using-alt-gr-to-switch-windows-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Unfortunately, you can't.

Long answer: Technically, if you change the left <kbd>alt</kbd>'s function, you would have to also alter the Application switcher's keyboard shortcut to something that doesn't use the <kbd>alt</kbd> keys.

Finally, I don't know if you're aware that you can also use the **System Settings > Keyboard Layout > Options...** to edit all kinds of keyboard layout related stuff.

Comment: So I can change the app-switcher’s keyboard shortcut? That would be useful as well: I could get used to windows-tab instead. Where do I change this?

Comment: Yes you can. You can customize (probably) all of the existing keyboard shortcuts. Go to `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts`. The App switcher shortcut will be under `Navigation > Switch Applications`. Change that (and all the other shortcuts that use `Alt L`) to something else, paying attention to not cause conflicts with existing shortcuts. That should do it.

Comment: P.S. I'm actually not sure if `Super+Tab` would work, because `Super` key is used for many important shortcuts in Unity (Super+Tab is already used to switch between Launcher's icons), so I'm guessing it would cause the same problem for you. But you can always try and let us know the results.

Comment: A recent update seems to have killed Unity on my machine so I can’t verify any of these suggestions but am going to award the bounty anyway.